# why doesn't the octave 3.6.4 for windows make automatically path for package folder?

Tags: octave

why doesn't the octave 3.6.4 for windows make automatically path for package folder?:

i installed octave 3.6.4 on my windows xp system and also all of packages.

'pkg list' operation shows every packages i've installed, but package folder does not be included in path list. (checked it by use 'path')

so i can't use 'fspecial' although i have packages in my 'share/ocetave/packages/image-2.0.0' folder.

My question body:

why does this situation happen?? isn't it normal that setup file make automatically link to path? i don't want to use 'addpath' function.

Answer (score 1):

Octave does not load packages by default, you need to load them. Use `pkg load image`. You can see which packages are loaded with `pkg list` that have an asterisk in front of their names.

Having to load a packages is that thing that many users coming from Matlab find strange but if you compare with other languages, such as Python, Perl, or C++, would you expect them to import, use, or #include every libraries available in the system by default? See [Octave's FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error) for more details.

If you want a package to be loaded automatically by default, the recommended action is to add the line `pkg load image` to your ~/.octaverc file.

Finally, you have just started with Octave, you should probably have installed Octave 3.8.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Octave 4.0.0 is released on May 29, 2015 and it has a GUI (Graphical User Interface) version as well as the regular CLI (Command Line Inteface) capabilities.

Your question is about Octave 3.6.4 and I am not sure this works on that version but on Octave 4.0.0, you can use an "-auto" option during package installation to make sure that the installed package does load automatically upon start. You can use the command as:

```
pkg install -auto <packagename>
```

For example, the following command will install the "image" package from the Octave-Forge repository and will load it automatically when starting Octave:

```
pkg install -auto -forge image
```

You can get more information here: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html

I do not know if this can also work with previous versions but it does work for 4.0.0...